# Python: print multiple tuples in a CSV file

Tags: python

I have several arrays of tuples which contain a float value for each month. Sample content for year 2020:

```
print(data2020)
[(-10.6,), (-25.11,), (-18.27,), (13.64,), (3.62,), (6.71,), (3.24,), (2.94,), (2.72,), (2.19,), (8.56,), (2.44,)]
```

I'd like to print the tuples for each month so that I can import them in a spreadsheet.
I see there's an handy csv module so I've come up with the following loop:

```
with open("out.csv", "w") as the_file:
    csv.register_dialect("custom", delimiter=" ", skipinitialspace=True)
    writer = csv.writer(the_file, dialect="custom")
    for month in range(0, 12):
        writer.writerow(str(data2020[month]) + ","+str(data2021[month]))
```

When I run the above loop, I get a weird csv output, with unwanted spaces and parenthesis:

```
( - 1 0 . 6 , ) , ( 1 3 . 7 6 , )
( - 2 5 . 1 1 , ) , ( 1 5 . 1 7 , )
( - 1 8 . 2 7 , ) , ( 1 2 . 8 2 , )
( 1 3 . 6 4 , ) , ( 3 . 5 5 , )
( 3 . 6 2 , ) , ( 1 1 . 2 4 , )
( 6 . 7 1 , ) , ( 8 . 2 2 , )
( 3 . 2 4 , ) , ( - 1 . 9 7 , )
( 2 . 9 4 , ) , ( - 4 . 9 6 , )
( 2 . 7 2 , ) , ( - 6 . 4 8 , )
( 2 . 1 9 , ) , ( - 2 . 1 9 , )
( 8 . 5 6 , ) , ( - 3 . 6 , )
( 2 . 4 4 , ) , ( - 4 . 0 4 , )
```

Ideally, each row should be formatted like this:

```
-10.6,13.76
-25.11,15.17
```

I've tried some combinations of delimiter but none helped. Could you give me an help? I'm open to use a different library/approach as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open("mydata.csv", "w").write("\n".join([f"{data[0]},{data[1]}" for data in list(zip(*[[data[0] for data in data2020], [data[0] for data in data2021]]))]))
```

or

```
with open("mydata.csv","w") as file:
    file.write("\n".join([f"{data[0][0]},{data[1][0]}" for data in zip(data2020, data2021)]))
```

you also can use `pandas` library:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({
    2020: data2020,
    2021: data2021
})
data.applymap(lambda x: x[0]).to_csv("out.csv", index = False, header=False)
```

Comment: The file doesn't get closed.

Comment: @TheThonnu yes, I know... but this is only a quick test and OP must use `with` as in question

Comment: Thanks a lot! works exactly as expected!!!

Comment: @Carla you're welcome, but I highly recommend to use `pandas` it is more readable and fast :) (I added how to using `pandas` in post)

Answer (score 1):

`writerow` takes an Iterable and iterates through it. In this case, you have passed a string, and therefore it is iterating over a string, character by character. Instead, use a list:

```py
writer.writerow([str(data2020[month][0]), str(data2021[month][0])])
```

Also, change the `delimiter` parameter in `register_dialect` to `','` if that's what you want.

You might want to check out the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

Comment: this still has a problem because each list element of data202X is a tuple. So instead what would work is: `writer.writerow([str(data2020[month][0]), str(data2021[month][0])])`

Comment: Thanks, I had just realised and was just about to update it with that...